# Elixir: Convert integer to unicode character

Tags: string, unicode, elixir

I want to iterate over the set of Chinese characters in Elixir given by Unicode. I read the documentation and it says I can use the '?' operator to get the codepoint as an integer and then can increment it. Now I just need to do the inverse, from codepoint to integer. Is there an easy way to do that? I did not find any. For instance, in Python you would do

```
>>> chr(ord("一") + 1)
    '丁'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no character data type in Elixir, but to convert a codepoint to a string containing that character (encoded as UTF-8), you can use either `<<x::utf8>>` or `List.to_string([x])`:

```
iex(1)> x = ?一 + 1
19969
iex(2)> <<x::utf8>>
"丁"
iex(3)> List.to_string([x])
"丁"
```

Comment: How to get unicode to be converted back to an integer ?

Comment: @DavidMagalhães use pattern matching: `<<x::utf8>> = "π"`. `x` will now be `960`.